# Radio button won't select in bootstrap btn-group

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following radio button group

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default active">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Ability must be a number." data-val-required="This field is required" id="Ability" name="Ability" type="radio" value="4">
            <span class="image-label">4</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input id="Ability" name="Ability" type="radio" value="3">
                 <span class="image-label">3</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
             <input id="Ability" name="Ability" type="radio" value="1">
             <span class="image-label">1</span>
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default">
             <input checked="checked" id="Ability" name="Ability" type="radio" value="0">
             <span class="image-label">0</span>
        </label>
</div>
```

With css to show the radio buttons that are normally hidden

```
.btn-group-vertical .btn input[type=radio] {
display: initial;
}
```

When clicking the labels or btns, the radio is checked as expected... but when clicking the radio, the btn is highlighted and the radio is **not** checked as expected. How do I make the radios check on click?

I'm using bootstrap.js v3.0.0

Edit: I found this relevant issue
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14137

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the bootstrap button.js is just for visual effects and not for the form logic.

But you can use a simple jQuery function to change this.

```
$('form').on('click', 'label.btn', function() {
  $('form').find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', false);
    $(this).find('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

[Working bootply](http://www.bootply.com/TcDm1sLLQO)

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, but it looks like there are some differences in bootstrap 3.3.0, for example I would need additional css to show the radio buttons, and they seem to behave when shown. I'll bear your example in mind when considering the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved this by overriding the bootstrap event handler

```
 $(document).off('click.bs.button.data-api')
 $(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^=button]', function (e) {
        var $btn = $(e.target)
        if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
        $btn.button('toggle')
        if (!$(e.target).is('input:radio')) {
            e.preventDefault()
        }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I forgot to include bootstrap's js in angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

If it saves someone some frustration..