# Radio buttons won't check in bootstrap button group

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap modal which contains a form, there are two radio style buttons inside that have been created based on the [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons) for normal button styled radio options:

```
<form id="changePlanForm" action="/change_plan_submit.php" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group-toggle active" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-outline-info active" for="1">
            <input type="radio" name="cycle" value="1" id="1" autocomplete="off" checked> Button 1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="2">
            <input type="radio" name="cycle" value="2" id="2" autocomplete="off">
        </label> Button 2
    </div>
</form>
```

However, when selecting a radio option the button will only appear "active" but will not become "checked". This is confirmed on submission of the form.

I had initially tried adding some JQuery as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33366090/radio-button-wont-select-in-bootstrap-btn-group):

```
<script>
    $('form').click (function() {
        alert("clicked");
        $('form').find("input[name='cycle']:checked").prop('checked', false);
        $(this).find("input[name='cycle']").prop('checked', true);
     });
</script>
```

but this script only removes the currently selected checked attribute and does not apply it to the new button.

Am I missing something in the script, or is there an easier way to create Bootstrap form buttons that behave like radio buttons?

Thanks in advance!

-- **Update 1** --

After doing some debugging it appears that when clicking on the label `$(this)` is not being defined and so there is nothing to set the checked property to true on.

Is there another way to identify the label that has been clicked on?

Comment: did you include the `bootstrap.js` file also?

Comment: @zgood yes `bootstrap.js` was included as a part of the [material dashboard package](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/material-dashboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use an `onchange` function to determine which `radio` button was checked and get its value using `.val()`

There is no need to set `prop` or `attr` for checked radio button to `false` or `true` on each click.

Run snippet below to see which `radio button` is `checked` on each click with a `change` function.

```js
$('form').on('change', function() { 
   //Get the checked radio button value
   var getCheckedValue = $('input[name=cycle]:checked').val()
   //console.log
   console.log('Radio ' +getCheckedValue+ ' is checked'); 
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="changePlanForm" action="/change_plan_submit.php" method="post">
  <div class="btn-group-toggle active" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-info active" for="1">
      <input type="radio" name="cycle" value="1" id="1" autocomplete="off" checked> Button 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="2">
      <input type="radio" name="cycle" value="2" id="2" autocomplete="off"> Button 2
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: your snippet works with `prop` or `attr`. I don't think this is the issue. You should use `prop` for the checked property, but attr will work also.

Comment: I've tried using `attr` instead but this doesn't work. When pressing the opposing button the active state changes to make it appear pressed but the checked state does not change. The script successfully removes the checked state from the button but does not add it to the new button.

Comment: @Aaron165 I have edited my answer and simplified as well and it working as exactly as you wanted. Let me know.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Thanks for all this, and you're right it _should_ work but when I added your console logging to my code it was showing that it wasn't changing. So that means there is something wrong deeper in my code which I'll get a friend to help me with in person. I'll check your answer as correct as it did help in the context of code extract.

Comment: @Aaron165 It should work just fine the same way its working here in snippet. I would suggest copy the exact code to see what going on there. Also just make sure you are loading the jQuery scripts properly. Happy coding.

Comment: On further inspection it seems that the bootstrap i'm using (set up by the friend i'm working on this with) hadn't correctly loaded jQuery. Now i've loaded the scripts correctly it's working. Many thanks for all your help @AlwaysHelping

Answer (score 1):

When a radio button (or a label containing a radio button) is clicked, it's checked property is automatically changed to true. Your current JQuery function, sets the the clicked radio button's checked property to false upon clicking, thus virtually making it impossible to be set to true.

If you just need to find out which radio button was clicked, the following JQuery code will work:

```
<script>
    $('form').click (function() {
        alert("clicked");
        let checkedOption = $('form').find("input[name='cycle']:checked");
        //checkedOption contains the radio that was just clicked
        //all other radios with the same 'name' will automatically turn false
     });
</script>
```